# How to get current category Id?

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to get the current category id (the id of the category I'm browsing on frontend).

```
 public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    Resolver $layerResolver,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    array $data = []
)
{
    parent::__construct($context, $data);

    $this->layerResolver = $layerResolver;
    $this->logger = $logger;
}

public function getCurrentCategory()
{
    return $this->layerResolver->get()->getCurrentCategory();
}

public function getCurrentCategoryId()
{
    return $this->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
}
```

I'm using layerResolver as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46414822

But I'm not getting the current id.

Answer (score 0):

I am supposing that you are on the category page with the handle of `catalog_category_view`

Try this

```
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class YourClass Extends AnyClass
{
    ...
    private $registry;
    ...

    public function __construct(Registry $registry) 
    {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    public function getCategoryId()
    {
        $currentCategory = $this->registry->registry('current_category');
        return $currentCategory->getId();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is work for me,

```
 protected $_registry;

 public function __construct(       
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    ){        
        $this->_registry = $registry;
    }
     public function getCurrentCategoryInfo()
    {        
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
    }
```

From getCurrentCategoryInfo() function you will get information
like,

```
    $currentCategory = $this->getCurrentCategoryInfo()
    $currentCatId = $currentCategory->getId(); //get current category id
    $currentCatName = $currentCategory->getName(); //get current category name
    $currentCatUrl = $currentCategory->getUrl();//get current category url
```

Thank you.